# REACT: If Else logic, greater than 100

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, for-loop

I have a react app that has a slider that moves icons between 0 and 100% by 2 inputs, **x** and **y**. But when the **y** input is less than **x**, it shoots the icons **LEFT** **style property** pass the range slider.

I want to create the logic so that if the icon **LEFT surpasses 100**, it **stays at 100**

for example, **x = 5** and **y = 10** so the icon would be half way at 50%

but if **x = 5 and y = 4**, the left property which would be 125%, the icon shoots and doesnt pass the slider but stays at 100%.

My issue is when I run the **for loop**, it moves all even **less than 100**% to **100%**

so if the icon was 10%, after the script it gets a value of **100%**

```
for(var i =0; i<= arrayOfIcons.length; i++) {
    if(arrayOfIcons[i].style.left <= '100%') {
        console.log(arrayOfIcons[i].style.left)
    } else {
        arrayOfIcons[i].style.left = '100%'
        console.log('greater than 100% : ' + arrayOfIcons[i].style.left)
    }
}
```

TL:DR if the value of is greater than 100%, i want it to stick to 100%

Comment: You are comparing if a number is less then/equal a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract numeric value from string with percent symbol.

```
function extractNumberFromPercentString(s) {
    return +s.slice(0, -1);
}

for(var i =0; i<= arrayOfIcons.length; i++) {
    if(extractNumberFromPercentString(arrayOfIcons[i].style.left) <= 100) {
        console.log(arrayOfIcons[i].style.left)
    } else {
        arrayOfIcons[i].style.left = '100%'
        console.log('greater than 100% : ' + arrayOfIcons[i].style.left)
    }
}
```